# log4j2 RollingFile not using date from log message for filePattern but current date

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I'm working on a program that generatse logs with different date-times. This is done by logging messages create from a custom class that implements [TimestampMessage](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/TimestampMessage.html).

I'm trying to output those logs into their respective corresponding files using the following log4j2 config:

```xml
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="Logs" filePattern="${log-path}/logs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
```

I expected that it would output log files for all the different dates with the corresponding logs in each, but I only get one: formatted with current date.

However, the log messages contained in the log file have the expected dates, e.g.:

```
09 Mar 2007 10:23:11 BLABLA
30 Aug 2008 02:56:29 BLABLA
03 Dec 2009 10:20:34 BLABLA
10 Apr 2010 22:47:46 BLABLA
10 Apr 2010 22:59:31 BLABLA
13 Aug 2015 12:36:26 BLABLA
```

Here I expected to get the following files:

```
/log-path/logs-2007-03-09
/log-path/logs-2008-08-30
/log-path/logs-2009-12-03
/log-path/logs-2010-03-10
/log-path/logs-2015-08-13
```

I think my biggest issue here is that `filePattern` of `RollingFile` uses the current date, while I was expecting it to use the log message date, just like `PatterLayout` does.

It is certainly possible to solve my issue through a custom appender, but it sounds like an incorrect solution to me here, so I was wondering, is there a way to make `RollingFile` use the date of the log message instead of the current date?

Comment: The date from the logging event is generated at the time of logging(method call log.info/log.debug..). If you say that you would expect to log something like 2007 when is 2021.. (on that computer) you simply cannot do it.

Comment: I think this is the whole point of creating a custom Message class that implements TimestampMessage and hence overrides the method `long getTimeStamp()`.  Maybe this isn't clear from the post, but I'm logging a custom message using https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#info-org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker-org.apache.logging.log4j.message.Message-

Comment: Please note that this is working with a custom  appender, the timestamp I get for the events is the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I could not find any clean way to do it, but there's an hack to do the trick if you run into this issue: creating a custom triggering policy that always returns `true` and set the current time file of the `PatternProcessor` to the time of the event.

Here's an example:

```java
@Plugin(name = "UnorderedLogTriggeringPolicy", category= Core.CATEGORY_NAME, elementType = Appender.ELEMENT_TYPE)
public class UnorderedLogTriggeringPolicy extends AbstractTriggeringPolicy {
    RollingFileManager manager;

    @Override
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(LogEvent logEvent) {
        if (manager != null) {
            // HACK: Set the time of the log File pattern processor using the time of the log event being processed
            manager.getPatternProcessor().setCurrentFileTime(logEvent.getTimeMillis());
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(RollingFileManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
        manager.getPatternProcessor().setTimeBased(true);
    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static UnorderedLogTriggeringPolicy createPolicy() {
        return new UnorderedLogTriggeringPolicy();
    }
}
```

Then you can add it to your log4j2.xml configuration this way:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" shutdownHook="disable" packages="PACKAGE_CONTAINING_TRIGGERING_POLICY">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">/tmp/outdatedLogs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="OutdatedLogger" filePattern="${log-path}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.logs">
            <Policies>
                <OutdatedLogEventTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="OutdatedLogger" level="INFO" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Again, this is probably not the cleanest solution to this issue, but this does the job. Hopefully this can help you.